# How to modify selected log messages to print to a different log file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I use log4j to print messages to log files in my Java project.

My current log file is set to log.INFO level and this builds a log file called **logFile1.log**

I want to print the same set of messages to a different log file (**logFile2.log**), with a selected number of messages slightly modified.

Code eg:

```
    log.info("Customer created");
    log.info("Customer name:" +customerName);
<instead of the above log message, here I want to print "ABC" in logFile2.log>
    log.info("Phone number added");
    log.info("Phone number:" +phoneNumber);
<instead of the above log message, here I want to print "DEF" in logFile2.log>
```

Here is how logFile1.log would look:

```
Customer created
Customer name:Bob
Phone number added
Phone number:123-456-7890
```

Here is how I want my logFile2.log to look like:

```
Customer created
ABC
Phone number added
DEF
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Log4j 1.x or Log4j 2?

Comment: I am using log4j 1.x

Comment: I can switch to log4j 2 if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this that I can think of. Both assume you are using a PatternLayout of Log4j2.

The first option is to use replace attribute of the PatternLayout. However, I am not aware that it is possible to replace multiple strings with different values from a single regex. This is more useful if you are trying to mask certain fields and replace them all with "****" or similar.

The second option would be to use a PatternSelector. In this option you would either use the ScriptPatternSelector or create a custom PatternSelector to compare the message text and choose the pattern to use. This would look like:

```
<PatternLayout>
  <ScriptPatternSelector defaultPattern="%m%n">
    <Script name="BeanShellSelector" language="bsh"><![CDATA[
       if (logEvent.getMessage() != null) {
         String msg = logEvent.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();
         if (msg.startsWith("Customer name:")) {
           return "CustomerName";
         } else if (msg.startsWith("Phone number:")) {
           return "PhoneNumber";
         }
         return null;
       } else {
         return null;
       }]]>
    </Script>
    <PatternMatch key="CustomerName" pattern="ABC%n"/>
    <PatternMatch key="PhoneNumber" pattern="DEF%n"/>
  </ScriptPatternSelector>
</PatternLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j.logger.logFile1 =DEBUG, file1Appender
log4j.logger.logFile2= DEBUG, file2Appender

log4j.additivity.logFile1=false
log4j.additivity.logFile2=false

log4j.appender.file1Appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1Appender.File=<path>/logFile1.log
log4j.appender.file1Appender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file1Appender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file1Appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1Appender.layout.ConversionPattern=<specify your pattern>

log4j.appender.file2Appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2Appender.File=<path>/logFile2.log
log4j.appender.file2Appender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file2Appender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file2Appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2Appender.layout.ConversionPattern=<specify your pattern>
```

And then you can log to different logger the messages? Have your own extended appender and modify the message before raising the event

Comment: How does this configuration change the resulting output as the OP asked?